# PHP Session Variables -> Accessing another unique identifier

Tags: php, session, variables, uniqueidentifier

I have a problem right now where, when a user logs in, their user object is stored in a session variable as to be quicker than making a database call each time.  The problem I am having is if something updates on their end (like the number of points they have), I have no way to modify that session variable, I can only update their row in the table.

Is there any way for php to access that session variable given it's unique identifier instead of reading from their cookie?  Or would it be better to check some flag in the database, and if the flag is set, update all the information?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you mean by "on their end". Do you mean that if some user data changes asynchronously (not in response to an action by the user) then you want to update the data, but can't write to the session?

Comment: Right, for example, user 1 makes a referral link, sends it to user 2.  When user 2 goes to that link, I want to update the number of points that user 1 has.  I can do that easily with a database call, but there is no way to update user 1's session information.

Comment: did you get any further with your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read it from a centralized storage (contrary to sessions). If you could, you should avoid the database calls. Use cache and update the cache on insert:

- *user 1* checks cache for *user 2*'s score

  - it's non-existing, so the call is forwarded to db
  - the score is still empty/0 so an entry in the cache is written like this: key: **"goals-2"** (unique identifier which is easy to figure out), value: **"0"**
- *user 2* scores a goal

  - the score for *user-2* is calculated by checking the cache (which is empty) and then checking the db (which is empty/0): 0 is current score
  - the new score is 0 + 1 = 1
  - the new score is inserted to database (for persistence), the cache with the key **"goals-2"** is saved with the key **"goals-2"** and the value **"1"**

then we're done, let's try the loop again:

- *user 1* checks cache for *user 2*'s score, finds **"1"**
- *user 1* checks cache again for *user 2*'s score, finds **"1"**

We're saving really many database calls here.

Some possible engines for caching are:

- [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.apc.php)
- [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php)

If you're on shared hosting, or unable to get PHP compiled with a good engine for caching, [writing to files](http://www.dangrossman.info/2007/01/03/simple-php-caching-example/) could do the job.

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is to create custom object which will hold data for example 5 minutes and than it will be reloaded. Just create object which will load your data from session, if loaded object is older than five minutes just reload data.

1. Load object
2. Check variable in object if (time()) its older than 5 min (or any custom time) reload data
3. If data reloaded update variable in object to new time and save it to session

I think this can resolve your problem

```
class MySession
{
    public $Duration = 0;
    public $Loaded = 0;
    public static function Load()
    {
        $obj = null;
        if(isset($_SESSION["my_session"]))
        {
            $obj = deserialize($_SESSION["my_session"]);            
            if((time()-$obj->Loaded)>$Duaration)
                    $obj = self::LoadObject();
        }
        else { $obj = self::LoadObject(); }
        $obj->Save();
        return $obj;
    }
    public function Save()
    {
        $_SESSION["my_session"] = serialize($this);
    }
    public static function LoadObject()
    {
        $obj = new MySession();
        $obj->Loaded = time();
        //logic for updating data
        return $obj;
    }
}
```